# Mutable borrow in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm new on Rust, i'm just doing some exercise.
There is a linked list. For example, **0->1->2->3->4**, cut it off at index 2, then reverse both, and then compose them. => **0<-1<-2** **3<-4** =>  **2->1->0->4->3**

```rust
#[derive(debug)]
struct Node{
    val: usize,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn new(i: usize) -> Node {
    ...
    }

    fn reverse_at(self, k: usize) -> Box<Node> {
        let mut prev = None;
        let mut curr = Box::new(self);

        let first_part_tail = &mut curr;

        let mut i: usize = 0;
        while i <= k {
            let next = curr.next.take();
            curr.next = prev;
            match next {
                Some(next_node) => {
                    prev = Some(curr);
                    curr = next_node;
                }
                None => return curr,
            }
            i += 1;
        }

        let head = prev.unwrap();
        prev = None;
        loop {
            let next = curr.next.take();
            curr.next = prev;
            match next {
                Some(next_node) => {
                    prev = Some(curr);
                    curr = next_node;
                }
                None => {
                    first_part_tail.next = Some(curr);
                    return head;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the mutable borrow of the first node**0**, and set **0**.next=**4** after getting the last node**4** at the end of function. But node**0**'s ownership is already been send to node**1**.
Obviously, `` error[E0499]: cannot borrow `curr.next` as mutable more than once at a time `` happens, i don't know what to do. This stuck me for a long time. Any help please.

[play.rust-lang.org/...](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=68521e3214b020258f81b8bc4a8d15d0)

`&`, i suppose this function would change the Node itself. And i don't know how to change self reference into the new node, so i used `self`. If someone can modify this, that helps too.
Maybe, change this function to

```rust
fn reverse_at(&mut self, k:usize){
    ...
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to include a complete example with main in Rust playground (https://play.rust-lang.org).  I started to take a look and noticed that you are mising `&` before self in your method signature.  see: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch05-03-method-syntax.html

Comment: @Ultrasaurus I've add the playground link. ```&```, i suppose this function would change the Node itself. And i don't know how to change self reference into the new node, so i used ```self```. If someone can modify this, that helps too.

Comment: Unrelated to your error, I don't see how your program creates a linked list... see playground example with just "new" https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd945b1e846217ac7d5acf2d0b45b9f1

Comment: I found this unofficial rust learning resource that has a lot of linked list examples that might be helpful: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: @Ultrasaurus The struct Node was from something else. Just ```Node::new(1234)```, this will create a linked list, 4->3->2->1->None. ```Node::new(1)``` will create 1->None. I'll look at the learning resource, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ultrasaurus thanks for the learning resource https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/. Now i solve the problem, although it takes several time.

The final code is here [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bd538fa094dfde6799798dd6696aa0cb)

There is a little bit weird, that my `LinkedNumber.head` is `Node`, cause the `LinkedNumber` always has a head, might be zero, but not null. Maybe it should be `Box<Node>`.

At line 71, i use `ptr::read`, it will

> Reads the value from `src` without moving it.

`mem::take` is ok, either. But it needs to initial `Node` with a default value by `trait Default`.

Than i use `Box::new` to move the node from stack into heap. (There's no necessary to do this, if `LinkedNumber.head` is `Box<Node>`)

At line 73, mark the raw_pointer `*const Node` of the head.

At line 94, if the link was break into two, cast `*const Node` into `*mut Node`, dereference it, set `(*ptr).next` with the last node of the original link.

How to test: change the number in `num.reverse_at(3)` at line 171, it works fine.